# Terminal returning: no crontab for user

Tags: bash, cron, useradd

I create a new user, john. Now I want to programmatically write a cronjob to the user john's crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
#script name: cronbuild.sh

cronjob1="0 */3 * * * /home/john/ad_dev/modem_dog.sh"
{ crontab -l -u john; echo "$cronjob1"; } | crontab -u john -
```

Now this does indeed write to john's crontab. However, the script returns:

```
tony@rpi:~ $: sudo ./cronbuild.sh
no crontab for user
tony@rpi:~ $
```

Confirming that it does write this to the user john's crontab...

```
tony@rpi:~ $: sudo crontab -u john -l
0 */3 * * * /home/john/ad_dev/modem_dog.sh
tony@rpi:~ $:
```

I guess the terminal returns

> no crontab for user

because it in fact does not have a crontab...? Seems obvious and not helpful.

So my question, why is it stating **no crontab for user**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is from `crontab -l -u john` you used in the script.

On one hand *you did* use the command. The only(?) reason to use it is to preserve the old crontab and append to it (not just overwrite it). This may be a good decision if there is an old crontab with arbitrary content you want to keep. This may be a bad decision if you run the script multiple times (lines you're adding will accumulate).

On the other hand you're saying the message is "obvious and not helpful", I guess because you *know* the user does not have a crontab (yet). But if you know for sure there is no crontab, then there is no need for `crontab -l …` in the first place. So *maybe* you don't need it.

The fact you used the command can be interpreted as if you expected (or at least allowed) the crontab to exist. So it's *reasonable* to warn you if it doesn't exist. This is what the command does. You can suppress the message by sending the stderr to `/dev/null`:

```
{ crontab -l -u john 2>/dev/null; echo …
```